# Fill and merge for booleen reduction

Tags: modeling, mesh

1- [I have a stl file (attached)](https://ufile.io/glthbv7w) for which I need to make a "footprint" by doing a boolean reduction on a cube, see image 1
[image: image 1]

2- I position my cube on the area I want to have in negative
[image: image 2]

3- I apply the boolean difference
[image: image 3]

4- The reduction is bad, As my initial file is not full, I can't get a clean reduction of my outline, all the shapes inside my initial file are interfering with the result
[image: image 4]

Here is the link to the stl

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to simplify you 3D scan with a 'decimate' modifier before the 'boolean' on your stack =)

[image: like this]

Good luck!